# Oracle - Query to populate dummy data based on other IDs

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a table A which has 1 million distinct ID's.

```
+---------+
|   ID    |
+---------+
| 1       |
| 2       |
| 3       |
| 4       |
| 5       |
| .       |
| .       |
| 1000000 |
+---------+
```

I have another table B  which has information about some of the ID's (Around 200) in the below format.
I have multiple measures (shown only 2)

```
+----+---------+--------+-------+
| ID | Measure | Month  | Value |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
|  1 | loss    | 1      | 200   |
|  1 | loss    | 2      | 180   |
|  1 | loss    | 3      | 250   |
|  1 | .       | .      | .     |
|  1 | .       | .      | .     |
|  1 | Balance | 1      | 100   |
|  1 | Balance | 2      | 140   |
|  1 | Balance | 3      | 500   |
|  1 | .       | .      | .     |
|  1 | .       | .      | .     |
|  2 | loss    | 1      | 140   |
|  2 | loss    | 2      | 300   |
|  2 | loss    | 3      | 250   |
|  2 | .       | .      | .     |
|  2 | .       | .      | .     |
|  2 | Balance | 1      | 500   |
|  2 | Balance | 2      | 210   |
|  2 | Balance | 3      | 330   |
|  2 | .       | .      | .     |
|  2 | .       | .      | .     |
+----+---------+--------+-------+
```

How can I scale Table B with dummy data (for the measure, month and value columns) to have information about all the 1 million ID's in A in Oracle?
I am looking for a query/stored procedure that can accomplish this task.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join`.  Here is one method -- assuming the ids are contiguous with no gaps:

```
select a.id, b.*
from a join
     (select b.*, count(distinct id) over () as num_ids
      from b
     ) b
     on mod(a.id, b.num_ids) = mod(b.id, b.num_ids);
```

If you cannot guarantee that the ids are contiguous:

```
select a.id, b.*
from (select a.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from a
     ) a join
     (select b.*, count(distinct id) over () as num_ids,
             dense_rank() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
     on mod(a.seqnum, b.num_ids) = mod(b.seqnum, b.num_ids);
```